# Pyspark command not found

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to install PySpark in Linux but when I am following several guides, it still gives me an error when I am trying to run `pyspark` in the terminal. It still gives me the message `Error: Pyspark not found`.

This is what I have:

in `~.bashrc` in the bottom:

```
export SPARK_PATH=~/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7

export $SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]
```

And in `ls`

```
root@kali~ spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7
```

Python version

```
Python 2.7.14+ (default, Dec  5 2017, 15:17:02) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
```

Java version

```
openjdk version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10.0.1+10-Debian-4)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10.0.1+10-Debian-4, mixed mode)
```

**Edit:** I tried using `source .bashrc` but it gives me an error:

```
bash: export: `/root/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/pyspark': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `--master': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `local[2]': not a valid identifier
```

How can I still add this in the code without getting an error?

**Edit2:** @Ramesh Maharjan solved the issue with the .bashrc, however I am still getting a Java error if I try to run Spark:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 71:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Comment: just add one more line in you `.bashrc` file export PATH = $PATH:SPARK_PATH/bin` and you should be good.

Comment: This line ``export $SPARK_PATH/bin/pyspark --master local[2]`` has an error: export is for setting/exporting environment variables. A variable needs a name, something like ``export VAR_NAME=VAR_VALUE`` ...

Comment: Thank you @RameshMaharjan this solved it. Now I just only need to solve the Java Error and I am running.